# Leibniz Integral Rule for probability distributions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Suppose $Y$ is a probability distribution with PDF and CDF, $f$ and $F$, respectively, and it is defined over nonnegative real numbers. I want to take the derivative of this function $F(\frac{x}{a}) \int_{0}^{\frac{x}{a}}y \:dF(y) -\int_{\frac{x}{a}}^{\infty}(ay-x)dF(y)$ with respect to $x$. I would be thankful to know how should I specify the conditions that $F^{\prime}(y)=f(y),\: F(\infty)=1, \: F(0)=0$.

```
D[F (x/a)*Integrate[y*f[y], {y, 0, x/a}] - Integrate[(y*a - x)*f (y), {y, x/a, Infinity}], x]
```

Comment: are you using $d$ both for the differential in the integral and for the name of a constant? if so please don't do that 

Comment: It was a bit confusing. I changed the variable. Could you please let me know how to add these assumptions?

Comment: just for the record, i tried, but wasn't able to get a reasonably simplified answer unfortunately. all I can help with is: mathematica syntax: `F (x/a)` should be `F[x/a]` and `f (y)` should be `f[y]` (otherwise this is multiplication, not function application), that you might be able to use `F'[y]` in place of `f[y]`, and that `Integrate` takes the `Assumptions` option (although I couldn't get it to change the outcome).

Comment: Yeah. Actually I made a mistake and I should replace "f(y)" by "f[y]". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a simple example so that you can see you get the same result as manual calculation.

```
D[Inactivate[Integrate[y*f[y], {y, 0, x/a}], Integrate], x]
(x f[x/a])/a^2
```

I will replace any references to F with the corresponding integral of f.

```
expression = Inactivate[
Integrate[f[y], {y, 0, x/a}]*Integrate[y*f[y], {y, 0, x/a}] - 
Integrate[(a*y - x)*f[y], {y, x/a, Infinity}], Integrate]
```

[image]
Differentiate and then Activate. You can also get your big F back into the expression with two substitutions.

```
 Activate[D[expression, x]]/.{Integrate[f[y],{y,0,x/a}]->F[x/a],
 -Integrate[-f[y],{y,x/a,Infinity}]->1-F[x/a]}
```

[image]

Which is the same as if you did the question manually using the product rule and
Leibnitz's rule.

Comment: Thank you so much